# `Text-overflow: ellipsis` for two items of a flex column, inside a flex row

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the following:

[image: Flex row of items and text, scribbled down]

It's easy to get ellipsis working for one item using:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

However in this example I have two items I want to truncate.

One needs to be underneath the other.

The issue I have is that as soon as the text goes inside a div (so that I can apply `flex-direction: column`), the `text-overflow: ellipsis` doesn't work because it's inside a container.

How can I achieve the above image's example with CSS?

Comment: Please show your attempts in a [mcve], otherwise this question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Answer (score -1):

You didn't supply us with a code, so I just made my own example of how it should work:

You have to limit your text containers' width (exactly where you added the ellipsis) for ellipsis to work (100% can work, depends on other styles).

```
.ellipsis {
    width: 200px;  //you have to set a width for the text to be trunced
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

example jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywcj5p26/